# Why does Synology DSM's "USB Copy" skip Umlaut-named files?

Tags: osx, file-copy, synology

**Background**

I have a large number of files from my mac that I first copied to a FAT32 hard drive and now migrated to a Synology NAS (DS216 with DSM 6 in my case, using ext4 internally) with `rsync`. I try to use Synology "USB Copy" to copy these files to another FAT32 USB volume. I would love to use this tool since it allows automatic triggering of copy jobs when a particular USB device gets connected.

**Problem**

USB Copy ends with a non-helpful error message

> The USB Copy task My_Backup_Task on
>   ds216 encountered unknown errors. The last error code is -10. Please
>   try again or contact Synology Support for assistance.

When I compare the source and destination file trees, some files are missing especially with Umlauts (äöü) in them.

Any ideas of why this is and how to fix it?

Answer (score 4):

**This is a Bug** in "USB Copy". OSX encodes Umlauts in a different way (NFD instead of NFC, see [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/10476/how-to-enter-special-characters-so-that-bash-terminal-understands-them) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6153345/different-utf8-encoding-in-filenames-os-x)). "USB Copy" is not able to deal with these names, it can only handle NFC encoded file names. Buried in the logs /var/log/usbcopyd.log.1.xz you can find something like

```
usb-copyd: [WARN] event-manager.cpp(192): EVENT is not NFC Form 'Event<EV_COPY> (WAITTING): [4] /path/filename_with_Umlaut_ä.JPG (file_op,file)', skipping...
```

... so they know they can't do this, but do not provide a helpful error message to the user :-(

A helpful **workaround** might be to use `convmv` to rename the files, according to [this blog](http://www.kantinen-blog.de/blog/?p=4216) you might be successfull with

```
pkg install perl
wget http://www.j3e.de/linux/convmv/convmv-1.15.tar.gz
tar xzvf convmv-1.15.tar.gz
cd convmv-1.15/
sed -i -e 's/usr/opt/1p' convmv
/opt/bin/convmv/convmv -f iso-8859-1 -t utf8 --notest -r /volume1/yourpath
```

See also this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12147410/different-utf-8-signature-for-same-diacritics-umlauts-2-binary-ways-to-write) for more details.

According to [this SF answer](https://serverfault.com/questions/397420/converting-utf-8-nfd-filenames-to-utf-8-nfc-in-either-rsync-or-afpd), you might also have avoided the problem when running `rsync` by using the `--iconv` option, e.g.

```
rsync -a --iconv=utf-8-mac,utf-8 localdir/ mynas:remotedir/
```

... but I am not sure if this is helpful when you have a mixed NFC / NFD directory tree.